# Having trouble retrieving collection from MongoDB database

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to learn MongoDB for my next project. I have installed MongoDB on my Windows 7 machine. I am able to create collection and retrieve data using mongo.exe. I am trying to use official C# driver to manipulate collection but my test console application goes in "abyss" while trying to connect to server (I guess).

I have written following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            // Create server settings to pass connection string, timeout, etc.
            var settings = new MongoServerSettings();
            settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27017);
            // Create server object to communicate with our server
            var server = new MongoServer(settings);
            server.Connect(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
            // Get our database instance to reach collections and data
            var message = string.Empty;
            server.IsDatabaseNameValid("test", out message);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
            var users = database.GetCollection("users").FindAll();

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User found");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Console application stops working on line *server.Connect()*. I have put this line just to find problem, I know it is not necessary to connect to server explicitly. If I remove that line then Console application stops working on line *foreach (var user in users)*

I also tried to get server using following code with no success:

```
 var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://<host>:27017");
 var server = mongoClient.GetServer();
```

Comment: can you confirm that MongoD is running at the time you're starting the application?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Code is perfect! It was idiosyncrasy of MongoDB that when you try to connect to MongoDB through C# driver, you will have to accept connection for first time. Next time onwards MongoDB will remember your last acceptance and move on.

There has to be setting to remove this condition but I haven't found it yet. I will update as soon as possible.

Happy MangoDB Learning.

Answer (score -1):

use your last example like this:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
var server = mongoClient.GetServer();
```

Unless it's not running on the same machine or not on the standard port